# $scope within anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, scope, anonymous

I have the following:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyAdapter) {       
   MyAdapter.getContactInfo(123, function(response) {
      $scope.contactInfo = JSON.parse(response.result);
   });        
}

app.service("MyAdapter", function() {
    this.getContactInfo = function(id, callback) {          
        thirdPartyAPI(id, callback);            
    };
});
```

Essentially my controller, calls a service to invoke an asynchronous function in a 3rd party api. I need to update the scope in controller with the response but it seems I don't have access to the scope from the anonymous function. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have access to the scope in the callback. What is probably happening is that because it's a 3rd party async call updating the scope, angular doesn't know about it. You need to use `$scope.$apply()` to trigger a digest cycle.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyAdapter) {       
   MyAdapter.getContactInfo(123, function(response) {
      $scope.contactInfo = JSON.parse(response.result);
      $scope.$apply();
   });        
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible that the 3rd party async returns the data before angular has completed the initial digest? In other words, is it possible $scope.apply will not be required?

Comment: @Anthony Chu: I saw an another way of using $apply(fn) with anomymous function inside. Which is better?